# Got error while update GEOMETRY field as empty in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, geometry, polygon

I got this below error while update the GEOMETRY field as ''

> Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

My query:

```
UPDATE `promocode` SET 
 `start_date` = '2018-02-14 00:00:00', 
 `expire_date` = '2018-02-28 00:00:00',
 `latitude` = '', 
 `longitude` = '', 
 `geofence_latlng` = '', 
 `geofence_polygon` = '',
 `promo_discount` = '10', 
 `promo_limit` = '5' 
WHERE `promoid` = '6'
```

Here `geofence_polygon` field datatype is `"polygon"`.

Comment: If you want to leave a column empty, use `NULL`, not `''`. An empty string is not a `polygon`.

Comment: Thank you  so much its working fine now